# Forwarding traffic between interfaces inside a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, firewall, docker

I have created a docker container executing the following command

```
docker run -it --net=none --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --name firewall ubuntu /bin/bash
```

after I have attached it two interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`. I need to forward traffic from eth1 to eth0. I have installed `` and applying the following simple rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have checked out that traffic arrive to interface eth1 by listening with tcpdump the interface eth1. Unfortunately I don't know the reason why the traffic is not forwarded to eth0. Any idea? All the flags have been properly set up to 1 on the system

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Did you set ip_forward to 1 in the container ?

Comment: the incoming traffic from the interface eth1 has to pass from the container to be evaluated from the iptables. Just a simple firewall. yes I have set the ip_forward already

Comment: But it also go through the docker bridge so you will duplicate conntrack sessions. Just to be sure can you add how you did set this kernel parameter and elaborate on interface IPs, route table and expected forwarded traffic source and destination ?

Comment: I'm not using docker bridge. I'm using openvswitch and the container is directly connected to the it

Comment: I'm going to post all my config

Comment: Xavier Lucas what do you want to see?